# Why my Google Chrome extension isn't saving data correctly using a Set()?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that will be able to remember some websites I visited. When I press the extension, there's a button (that allows the user to save the current URL of the tab and the title) and an “a” element, that  will redirect to the URL saved. The idea is making it able to save different URLs, but first I want it able to save one.

Someone told me to do that with a Set(). I've the code, but something is wrong so when I press the “a” element with the last saved element, it opens that direction: `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/[object%20Set%20Iterator]` or: `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/[undefined]`.

What I'm doing wrong? I've been searching for a while but I don't see anything wrong. Thanks!

```js
var urlSet = new Set();
var titleSet = new Set();

chrome.storage.sync.get(["activeTab", "nameOfTheTab"], function(items){
  urlSet.add(items.activeTab);
  titleSet.add(items.nameOfTheTabs);

  document.getElementById('urlDude').href = [...urlSet];
  document.getElementById('urlDude').innerHTML = [...titleSet];
  
});

saveItem.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

    urlSet.add(tabs[0].url);
    titleSet.add(tabs[0].title);

    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "activeTab": [...urlSet] }, function(){  });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "nameOfTheTab": [...titleSet] }, function(){  });
    document.getElementById('urlDude').href = [...urlSet];
    document.getElementById('urlDude').innerHTML = [...titleSet];

 });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./popus.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="saveItem">save</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a id="urlDude" target="_blank"><p>Hola</p></a>
      <a id="urlDude2" target="_blank"><p>Hola2</p></a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have now:

```js
var urlSet = new Map();

chrome.storage.sync.get(["activeTabs"], function(items){
if(!items.activeTabs)
 return;
urlSet = new Map(JSON.parse(items.activeTabs));
AddLinks();
});

function AddLinks()
{
  var myLinks="";
  urlSet.forEach(function(value, key) {
    //myLinks+="<a href='"+value+"' target='_blank'>"+key+"</a> <span>X</span><br>";

    pushingData(value, key);
  });

  //document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML  = myLinks; 
}

saveItem.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {

  urlSet.set(tabs[0].title, tabs[0].url);

  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "activeTabs":JSON.stringify(Array.from(urlSet.entries())) });
  pushingData(tabs[0].url, tabs[0].title);
  });
};

function pushingData(value, key) {
  var atags = document.createElement("a");
    atags.href = value;
    atags.innerHTML = key;
    
    document.getElementById('mydiv').append(atags);

    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerHTML = "x";
    newButton.addEventListener('click', function() { urlSet.delete(key); });

    document.getElementById('mydiv').append(newButton);
    
    var breakLine = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById('mydiv').append(breakLine);
};
```

Comment: Use `[...urlSet]`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. What do you mean? Where does I have to put that? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `urlSet.keys()`.

Comment: I've just updated the code with that you have said to me (you can see it in this Stack's post, I've updated it), but I get the same. The only difference is that when I press the a, I receive `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/[object%20Set]` instead of `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/[object%20Set%20Iterator]`

Comment: Reread my first comment please.

Comment: So, `var urlArray = [...urlSet];`?

Comment: @wOxxOm I've just updated the code with what have you said, but now I receive a `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/oneOfTheUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved,another`.

Comment: What happens if you replace currentWindow: true with windowType:"normal" ?

Comment: I get the same that with currentWindow: true. When I click the extension, the "a" tag urlDude is empty. When I press the save button, the urlDude now redirects me to `chrome-extension://the_key_of_my_extension/oneOfTheUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved,another`, but the title is the same as the table I've just saved.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not working for you. If you add alert(tabs[0].url); to the start of the callback, will it have the correct url or your extension url?

Comment: I get the correct url.

Comment: You keep adding urls to urlSet and then read them all, so no wonder you get oneOfTheUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved,anotherUrlSaved, that's what [...urlSet] contains, the question is where is the extention url comes from, try cleaning storage and adding just one url

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm wondering: where does the extension url comes. I've just closed the computer, tomorrow I'll try it and send you the output. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code (with some slight modifications) in my extension and it worked, so I suspect there might be something stuck in the storage from your previous attempts. Here's what I've got:

```
var urlSet = new Map();

chrome.storage.sync.get(["activeTabs"], function(items){
if(!items.activeTabs)
 return;
urlSet = new Map(JSON.parse(items.activeTabs));
AddLinks();
});

function AddLinks()
{
  //There are better ways of doing this!
  var myLinks="";
  urlSet.forEach(function(value, key) {
    myLinks+="<a href='"+value+"' target='_blank'>"+key+"</a>";
  });

  // You may want to come up with a way to delete links 
  //before they get out of control and proclaim independence 
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML  = myLinks; 
}

saveItem.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {

  urlSet.set(tabs[0].title, tabs[0].url);

  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "activeTabs":JSON.stringify(Array.from(urlSet.entries())) });
  AddLinks();
  });
};
```

UPDATE
Seems like adding inline scripts to the popup is causing security issuer. While it is probably possible white-list your page to use its own script a better way of adding new elements is creating them with document.createElement, rather than generating a sting, to give you an idea of how it may look:

```
 var delButton = document.createElement("button");
delButton.innerHTML = "delete";
delButton.addEventListener('click',function(){/*something useful happens here*/});
document.getElementById('mydiv').append(delButton);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! This worked for me. Just for finish, I've never used a Map. What is the syntax for deleting a specific item from the array? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! To delete use urlSet.delete('Title of the page you want to delete')

Comment: Me again. :( I try to delete an url of the list, but I get an error! I'm trying to make that, when I hover the mouse into the title of the url in the extension, it gets deleted. I added to every a tag the onmousehover event, and this linked to a function. But this isn't working, because I get `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.` What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it, but how are you planning to click on URLs if hovering over them is deleting them? Why not to add a button next to the 'a' tag?

Comment: You're right, that would be a bad idea haha. It's better the button. But my trouble is that I can't execute inline code. I'm trying to make the delete button, but I can't. How can I get the title of the specific link I'm clicking?

Comment: If you add buttons inside the foreach loop, just call  a function with the key as a parameter (something like deleteMyLink(key) instead of the comment I left in my update) and inside that function delete the entry from urlSet and trigger link re-draw

Comment: I've followed your update on the answer (sorry, I didn't see it before!) but the buttons aren't been created.

Comment: You sure you're not setting innerHTML  directly anymore? if you append buttons you need to append links too, or you just replace buttons with links

Comment: I've just updated into the post what I have. I'd like to delete with the x span, but the buttons would be great too. But they didn't appear.

Comment: Your spans should appear, I don't why they wouldn't. However you cannot add events to them, so they are a bit useless. Create all elements with  document.createElement([tag name such as span or a]); append them to the div and and remove document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML  = myLinks

Comment: Hey! Me again. I've just updated the code I have. I append the a and the button, but when I press the link, it doesn't work (unless I right-click it). The buttons are not working (I tried alert(key) and it showed me the correct title), I can't use them for deleting with `urlSet.delete('key')`. Please apology all the work I'm giving to you. :(

Comment: Hey! No problem :) have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/7mewkho4/ I left some comments in your code

Comment: Ooh, I see! I forgot the target! I've just fixed it. But for the delete button, I should delete all the mydiv content and do the foreach again?

Comment: Well, if you want it to be more optimized, you can wrap the link and button into a div, assign it an id and then find and delete just that div by id. But a complete redraw is easier to do, I'd start with that, if it gets too slow you can always change it

Comment: So... the URLs are disappearing from the URL list when I press the button, but when I re-open the extension, the link that I delete is there, it doesn't disappear. :(

Comment: If on delete you update local storage too they will stop it :)

Comment: And... How can I delete the local storage? :(

Comment: And how does deleting from local storage differ from adding to it? (hint - it doesn't, use chrome.storage.sync.set :) )

Comment: Aaaaa, really thanks!! This is working. ^^ Really thanks for all your help and your patience, and please apology all that work I've given to you. :( I wouldn't be able to do this without your help. Really, thanks! It's fully functional. Thanks!